# How do I load a specific Asset Bundle Manifest, but not the Asset Bundle itself?

Tags: unity, asset-management, streaming-assets

I have a bunch of Asset Bundles.  I load the generic Asset Bundle Manifest to get the names of all of my asset bundles.  I want to load only a specific asset from the bundle, but I need to retrieve the names of the assets so I can choose which one.  The names of these assets are in the asset bundles manifests associated with each asset bundle.

How can I load just the manifest for a particular asset bundle?

This is the closest I have come, but it does not work:

```
private IEnumerator LoadAssetNames()
{
    foreach (var bundleName in assetBundleNames)
    {
        string url = "my://server/" + bundleName + ".manifest";
        var www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(url);
        yield return www.Send();
        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
            yield break;
        }
        var bundle = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)www.downloadHandler).assetBundle;
        www.Dispose();
        assetNames[bundleName] = bundle.GetAllAssetNames();
    }
}
```

It returns to me a failed to decompress error:

```
Error while downloading Asset Bundle: Failed to decompress data for the AssetBundle 'my://server/bundleName.manifest'.
```

I can download the manifest directly as a string or set of bytes, but then how can I cast it to an `AssetBundleManifest`?

Comment: will it work if you replace the .manifest to .unity3d?

Comment: Sorry to necro this. But did you ever figure out how to do this? Trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is relevant or not any more but loading a manifest- according to Unity's docs requires loading the bundle and then grabbing the manifest.

```
string url = "my://server/" + bundleName
```

Instead of

```
string url = "my://server/" + bundleName + ".manifest"
```

[Using AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Native.html)